# How to prevent a user from sending emails from a shared mailbox in the web version of Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to forbid a user to send emails from a shared mailbox manually?

I only need to programmatically send emails from the address of the shared mailbox through the Graph API, and not give the user the ability to send emails manually.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's impossible. You can't detect if the message has been sent manually or programmatically.